# Hive table created with Spark not visible from HUE / Hive GUI

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I am creating a hive table from scala using the next code:

```
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("self service")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark.sql("CREATE TABLE default.TEST_TABLE (C1 INT)")
```

The table must be successfully created, because if I run this code twice I receive an error saying the table already exists.

However, when I try to access this table from the GUI (HUE), I cannot see any table in Hive, so it seems it's being saved in a different path that the used by Hive in HUE to get this information.

Do you know what should I do to see the tables I create from my code from the HUE/Hive web GUI?

Any help will be very appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you included hive-site.xml to your spark submit? If not provided spark will create a new Hive database. You can test if you connect with Hive by running  spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES") . If only default exists (and you have created another one previously) you have not yet connected with  Hive. Also do you use YARN?

Comment: Hi @MichailN, thank you very much for your answer. That makes sense. Unfortunatelly I am kind of newby with these technologies, so I'm trying to include the hive-site.xml in the spark code without success. Could you please give me a clue about how doing it? Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seems to me you have not added hive-site.xml to the proper path.
Hive-site has the properties that spark need to connect successfully with Hive and you should add this to the directory

> SPARK_HOME/conf/

You can also add this file by using [spark.driver.extraClassPath](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) and give the directory where this file exists. For example in pyspark submit

```
/usr/bin/spark2-submit \
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/../ Directory with Hive-site.xml / \
--master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory nG --executor-memory nG \  
--executor-cores n myScript.py
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MichailN. At the end it worked adding two configurations to the SparkSession, the spark.sql.warehouse.dir and the hive.metastore.uris, but your help has been crucial to find the solution. Thanks!